# Update Textbox control bound to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, prism

I need to update a `TextBox` that's bound to a property. In the way I've implemented it it's working fine. Here's the code

```
private double foo;

public double Foo
{
  get { return foo; }
  set
  {
    foo = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo);
  }
}
```

But now I need to update the value of this property from another property and the `TextBox` bound to Foo is not updated. Here's the code

```
private string foo1

public string Foo1
{
  get { return foo1; }
  set
  {
    foo1 = value;
    foo = 4; // Updating the Foo property indirectly
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo);
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo1);
  }
}
```

I'm obligated to update the value of the property Foo in that way because Foo and another property are updated each other so I can't update the properties directly because I fall in an infinity recursion.

The question is How I can update the `TextBox` that is bound to the *Foo* property when I change the value of the attribute **foo**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you should update the public member `Foo` in your `Foo1` setter.  That will cause the `RaisePropertyChanged` event to fire for `Foo`.

```
private string foo1

public string Foo1
{
  get { return foo1; }
  set
  {
    foo1 = value;
    Foo = 4;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo1);
  }
}
```

You could call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo);` whenever you update your private field `foo`, but unless there is a good reason not to use the property `Foo`, I would always use it over `foo`.  The intention of `set` is to have that code run whenever the value of the property changes.  In my opinion, setting the private field bypasses the code in `set` which violates this intention.

**EDIT**

On another note, if you only want to call `RaisePropertyChanged` and change the value of `Foo` when `Foo1` *changes* (not necessarily each time the setter is called), just add a check to see if the value has changed. This will take care of your recursion problem.

```
set
{
    if(foo1 != value)
    {
       foo1 = value;
       Foo = 4;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => Foo1);
    }
}
```

Comment: like I said in the post I can't update the property directly because that property update another property Foo1 and Foo1 update Foo so the only option I've is to update the attributes of both properties and in some way update the TextBoxes binded to each property

Comment: like you said the "if" solved the recursion problem. Thank you for your help